# What are good ruby-debug alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I'd heard some discussion on a Ruby podcast about a debugger that allowed you to use linux style commands to traverse through an object.  Like for example you have a object, with attributes foo and bar, you can actually cd to foo, ls to view it's attributes, cd to another object, etc etc.  But I can't find this for the life of me!!!

Does anyone know the name of this debugger, or any other good alternatives?

Comment: what was the name of the podcast that mentioned this tool? i'd love to hear it! :)

Comment: It was this one: http://rubyshow.com/episodes/181.  It's a great show, though I think it's a little too heavy on the unfunny banter :)

Comment: can you tell me where abouts in that podcast (i.e time) they mention it? i can't seem to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're talking about [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) which was [discussed a while back here](http://rubyrogues.com/debugging-in-ruby/).